# Is there a way to pull tweets from twitter for free?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter-api-v2

Since twitter has removed the ability to get tweets in the free tier of their API. Is there an alternative?

I could try a web scraper. Do you guys have any recommendation for that. My primary language of use is python.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Web scraping *could* violate the Twitter terms of service if you do it the wrong way; see https://research.aimultiple.com/twitter-web-scraping/.  And ask a lawyer.  And it is not called Twitter anymore ...

Comment: i know that. I don't care about the terms of service. It's for a small text classifiation project. Who cares. But i understand your concern. I will try discord